# Save multiple checkboxes in a variable to be shown later?

Tags: javascript, jquery

is there a way to for example have checkboxes that store their variable to be shown in a div later?

for example, I check off:
BMW
Mercedes
Volvo
Fiat

When I press a submit button, those that I checkmarked will be shown like this:
Manufacturers: BMW, Mercedes, Volvo, Fiat.

Do you think this is possible without php?
Thank you :))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is a script that takes the checked elements and shows them in a div on submit http://jsfiddle.net/vrpMc/

note: this doesn't actually store the data anywhere. So this is only really useful if you have some other plan for the data

edit: http://jsfiddle.net/vrpMc/3/ (fixes a typo)

Comment: How about when I want to use 2 different forms? I tried this and they share both data even when I changed the "htmls" and "cars[]" variable.

Comment: change the selector that checks for checked checkboxes. (silly sentence)
see: http://jsfiddle.net/vrpMc/6/

Answer (score 2):

You can use [jQuery's cookie plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/files/jquery.cookie.js.txt) to set it into cookies and use it from cookies

Comment: Cool :) Do you think, however that the amount of people who have cookies disabled is negligible?

Comment: @pufAmuf: I have never seen even one user with diabled cookies

Answer (score 2):

If you're concerned the user may have cookies disabled and thus don't want to use the cookie plugin, you should look into [jStorage](http://www.jstorage.info/), a plugin that utilizes HTML5 local storage and userData in IE.

It is very compatible, and I would bet almost every user has some sort of local storage functionality enabled (I don't even know how to disable it, unlike cookies).

> Current availability: jStorage supports all major browsers - Internet Explorer 6+, Firefox 2+, Safari 4+, Chrome 4+, Opera 10.50+

Comment: This is great! I might use it in some of my other projects, thanks SK :)